# Simple URL rotator with php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I  am trying a build a url rotator where next url will be displayed under a hyper link.

```
<a href="$URL[]">Next</a>
```

I am able to retrieve all the enteries from the table and save them into array. But i dont know how to display them one by one under hyper link and on  link click next url should be displayed.

Code I am using

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
$Id[] = $row['id'];
$Name[] = $row['name'];
$URL[] = $row['url'];


}
```

To Display

```
$x=0;
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {

echo "$Id[$x]";  
echo "$URL[$x]";
echo "$Name[$x]";
echo "<br>";
}
```

Please throw some suggestion on how to achieve this task.

Comment: _under hyper link and on link click next url should be displayed._ does not any meaningful information

Comment: Do you need some kind of pagination....???

Comment: I thought about pagination earlier .. but wanted a more simpler method for this.. Its a simple url rotator. with next button on top. and next record should be displayed on click.

Comment: you need to fixed the loop in each page and pass the url number, because you are demanding like individual pages..

Comment: can you give any example please

Comment: sure, wait i am going to make an example

Comment: something like this: [https://3v4l.org/vvZ94](https://3v4l.org/vvZ94)

Comment: yes. but how will it generate the next url. e.g. url1 is displayed on first click. url2 should be displayed on 2nd click and so ...

Comment: this is dynamic...., just need to change the `$URL[$urlNo]` to `$URL[$urlNo+1]`

Comment: ok. let me check it out ... then i will reply

Comment: Check this: [https://3v4l.org/SgsfV](https://3v4l.org/SgsfV)

Comment: please write your answer seperately .. $_GET['urlno'];  where will it get this value.

Answer (score 0):

if problem just to count array index.used this code:

```
for($x = 0; $x <= count($Id); $x ++) {

    echo $Id[$key];  
    echo '&nbsp<a href="'.$URL[$key].'">Next</a> &nbsp';
    echo $Name[$key];
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

if make pagination?
change code:

```
$curent = isset($_Get['page']) ? $_Get['page'] : '0';
// 10 number row in fetch DB
$count = $curent == '0' ? 10 : ($count - 1) * 10;

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from TABLE limit $curent,$count");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
  $Id[] = $row['id'];
  $Name[] = $row['name'];
  $URL[] = $row['url'];
}
// sample url = index.php
$url = 'index.php?page='. ($curent == '0' ? $curent+2 : $curent + 1);
```

To Display link to next page:

```
<a href="<?php $url ?>">Next</a>
<?php
    for($x = 0; $x <= count($Id); $x ++) {

        echo $Id[$key];  
        echo '&nbsp<a href="'.$URL[$key].'">Next</a> &nbsp';
        echo $Name[$key];
        echo "<br>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: it displays all the links at once. I only need to display on NEXT , and on each next click . next url should be displayed in iframe or div etc

Comment: display one by one fetch data in Db?

Comment: did not get ur qeustion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the `$URL` array in your hand, so count the array. Get the `$get_url_no` and check it is less than the total url or not if yes than make the `$get_url_no` + 1, so you can access the next url. add this link to the url so you can get it from the url using `$get_url_no = $_GET['urlno'];`.

```
$count = count($URL);
$get_url_no = $_GET['urlno'];    
$urlNo = (isset($get_url_no) && $get_url_no < $count) ? ($get_url_no + 1) : 0;
$url = $URL[$urlNo]."&urlno=".$urlNo;
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Next</a>';
```

Comment: Did you check this line: `$url = $URL[$urlNo]."&urlno=".$urlNo;`?

Comment: This is your array index of `$URL`, so you can access the array.

Comment: make a try with your script and see what happen.

Comment: $get_url_no = $_GET['urlno'];  . Error 502. When  i use this ---
$get_url_no = $_GET['Id'];  .. it works fine ... it displays the next button with and url to click.

Comment: it does not increment the url though

Comment: Is your URL holds the id of `$ID[]` value??

Comment: id= autoincrent filed.   url = website url . name= website name.

Comment: What i did, I am sure it did the things you want. Here is not enough resource to make a complete answer for you.

Comment: I have used exactly your  code .. and it display link value like this . http://www.website.com/&urlno=0 ... http://www.website.com/ ..this is stored in db.

Comment: the problem with the `.com/&`, I think you have the querystring already.

Comment: it should be like `website.com?urlno=0`

Comment: No. it should display ...  website.com ... only. where members can click and navigate to the url .